# Cypress adds /__/#/ to links when i use cy.visit(),

Tags: cypress

```
describe("A full test of the reddit site", function(){
    it("visits the page and logs in", function(){
        cy.visit("www.reddit.com/")
        cy.get("a:contains('log in')").click()
        var url = cy.url()
        console.log(url)
    })

})
```

[The screenshot of how the exact url looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNoUp.png)

It goes to http://www.reddit.com/__/#/tests/integration/examples/reddit.js instead of reddit.com

Comment: but on your screenshot, it is clearly said that `Your requested URL has been blocked as per the directions received from Department of Telecommunications, Government of India`
FYI I have checked it on my PC and it works perfectly.

Comment: I've tried different things but in each and every of them the trailing extra string /__/#/cypress/tests/integration is added.How did you prevent the extra string?
Because of this extra addition, cy.visit() never goes to the correct link. For a long time, it said 404 not found. 

But cy.visit() does work on other websites like thehindu.com (a newspaper site). 
I dunno what the difference is.How did you prevent the extra string?@EvgeniiBazhanov

Comment: well now I also see this recorded a video for you [here](https://monosnap.com/file/YafCLMnEpgW2akmrsgeGUt1bEzQNGA)
also have tried on different cypress version 4.1.0 - 4.3.0